# Difference between formula of SNR and SQNR?

Tags: snr, quantization, analog-to-digital

[image: snapshot of DSP SE question]

Is there any difference between formula/expressionsof SNR and SQNR? where SNR is Signal to noise ratio and SQNR is signal to quantization noise . The following DSP SE question shows both SNR and SQNR to be same as also shown highlighted/encircled in attached snapshot. It uses the formula of SNR under heading of SQNR

[What are advantages of having higher sampling rate of a signal?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40259/what-are-advantages-of-having-higher-sampling-rate-of-a-signal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between snr vs sqnr?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63794/what-is-difference-between-snr-vs-sqnr)

Comment: You really got helpful comments to your previous question on the difference between SNR and QSNR. But you chose not to specify where your doubts come from. Now you've got the third place where we tell you the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same; the SNR as limited by quantization noise specifically is SQNR. SNR is signal to noise ratio in general without being specific as to the noise source.  SNR is equal to SQNR when quantization noise is the dominant noise source.