# Simulating quantization of ADC using device SNR

Tags: python, snr, analog-to-digital, quantization

Suppose I have ADC microphone with a given SNR in the sense that is related to its quantization. From [this tutorial](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-001.pdf) we have the following connection how bit-depth determines SNR, Eq. (9):
$$
\mathrm{SNR} = 6.02 \times N + 1.76 \ \mathrm{dB}
$$
where $N$ is the bit-depth.
I would like to  invert this relation in Python. Generate a float32 signal and quantize it as if it was recorded by an ADC microphone with the given SNR.

My original Python code was:

```
bits = int((snr_mic - 1.76)/6.02)
quant = 2**bits
out_audio = np.floor(audio * quant).astype(int)/quant
```

Later, I modified the code to this:

```
bits = np.floor((snr_mic - 1.76)/6.02) + 1
quant = 2**bits
out_audio = (audio * quant).astype(int)/quant
```

Since it enforces a signal simulated to be recorded with 0 dB SNR mic to be all 0's.
However, even signals simulated to be recorded with 5 dB of SNR mic was all 0's.
So I probably have bug in my code, probably related to the fine difference between `floor` and `int` for negative numbers.

What is the correct way to do it and have nonzero quantized signals for a given nonzero SNR mic?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ADC microphone". Do you want to model A_ the noise of an ADC quantization. B) the self noise of a microphone or C) the typically acoustic background noise that dominates most microphone recordings? These are all very different things. If someone uses the term "SNR of a microphone recording" they typically mean C) or B). A) is rarely a significant issue

Comment: A 1-bit microphone would have an SNR of 7.8dB -- why are you surprised that a calculation that specifies fewer than one bit(s) has all zeros as an output?  As a debugging aid, printing out your 'bits' and 'quant' numbers would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

5 dB is not a sensible value for a formula whose minimum result would be 7.78 dB for $N=1$. So, your test case is "broken", and correctly, you get a 0-bit quantization (i.e., no values at all).

Even for higher SNRs: This sounds pretty reasonable!

Your audio will rarely come close to maximum amplitude. Think about this: if you only had, say, two bits, then that's 1 bit for the sign (think your audio as shifted to be centered around 0 if it helps), and 1 bit leading to two amplitude steps. If your audio recording always keeps more than 6 dB headroom (to avoid clipping!), then that quantization leads to all-zero.

Audio ADCs are pretty good, and I'd have no problem calling anything with a QSNR < 32 dB "atrocious".

---

Note that your considerations also has another shortcoming:

The formula you cite only applies to signals that are uniformly distributed over exactly the full ADC range. You'll be *very* hard tasked finding an audio signal that even remotely looks like that! For clipping / linearity / crest factor reasons, you need to have headroom for the vast majority of audio samples. Then, speech, music and many noise sources do not resemble uniformly distributed values:

[image: Unnormalized histogram: triangle with tails nearly reaching max. amplitude]
<sup>Unnormalized 100-bin histogram over the values in Devin Townsend's *Kingdom*, a song that definitely tries to also achieve high amplitudes.</sup>

[image: Unnormalized Histogram: Pretty much a triangle]
<sup>Unnormalized 100-bin histogram over the values in Nightwish's [*Angels Fall First*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0aPO33Wesw), a song that contains clean vocals and acoustic guitar playing.</sup>

As you can see, assuming all values are equally probable is very far from the truth; accordingly, the actual quantization noise (the difference between quantized and original signal) does not follow the oft-cited formula. Whether or not that's a problem to you, I can't tell: it depends on what you want to show. However, "I have an audio SNR of x dB, thus I must have an ADC with (x-1.76)/6.02" is a fallacy.

Comment: Most signals will be distributed over a quantization interval as long as the signal spans a few quantization levels between samples (similar to making random white noise generators through modulo math). The main point about the formula is that it is applicable to the signal being a sine wave specifically (with a variance of Vpp/8 compared to the variance of noise as q/12).

Comment: That comment should have more than my upvote, @DanBoschen

Comment: Just being helpful (I hope and not coming across as too critical) but if you agree, please update your answer and I will upvote and delete my comments  (I is the magnitude distribution of the noise that is uniform while the signal distribution is bowl shaped as a sinusoid spends more time at the edges). I’ve confirmed other distributions and it all matches it is just a matter of peak to average for whatever waveform you test with and what exactly “peak” is. (Easy to define for a sine wave).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let us suppose I still want to simulate quantization using that model and formula. I understand that SNR < 8 dB will give me rubbish, but still: what is the correct implementation of the quantization?

Comment: Your quantization model as is looks correct, you'd want to use `int` instead of `floor` (`floor(-0.1) == -1`), to get lower average error.

Comment: @DanBoschen I meant to fix the answer, but didn't get around to doing it yet. Also, it deserves a bit more math, namely, if we model things as having headroom (i.e., the amplitude PDF having support that's a true subinterval spanning only a fraction of the full ADC scale), does that have significant influence on the QSNR (my guess *now*, after considering your comment, is: it has influence, but not much, as we reduce error within the values that actually occur, but we also reduce signal power)

Comment: @MarcusMüller  You refer to the 2nd block of code, right? If I use ```int``` instead of ```floor``` I would need to cancel the +1? For positive numbers ```int``` should be the same ```floor```.

Comment: @MarcusMüller See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40259/what-are-advantages-of-having-higher-sampling-rate-of-a-signal/40261#40261  I simulated this in the past with backing off from full-scale and decreasing number of bits and different distribution with interesting results-- if someone ever asks a related question I can post those results, but it is  completely independent of back-off (reduces db for db) as long as we meet the first criteria I gave on what makes the quantization noise approximately a white noise process with uniform distribution.

Comment: Also rounding and truncation give the same error other than introducing a DC offset (which typically is not included in noise power similar to not including the mean in the standard deviation and variance).

Comment: In my applications there is no DC component. All the signals are simulated by Python. My current code is ```bits = np.floor((snr_mic - 1.76)/6.02) + 1 ;
quant = 2**bits ;
out_audio = (audio * quant).astype(int)/quant ; ``` where ```;``` is end command. I think it is correct but I don't know if to use int or floor because of the different effects on negative numbers.