Why is quantization noise in Delta-Sigma ADCs considered uniform?
I don't work with data converters now and this is a question from 10 years ago. While I was at college, during an ADI summer camp evaluating AD7176-2 I learnt about $\Delta-\Sigma$ ADCs and was attracted by how different they are compared to traditional ADCs. At that time, I had this question:
In a lot of texts and tutorials, Quantization Noise(QN) is considered an additive noise whose spectrum is uniform across all frequencies, the lower the resolution of the ADC, the higher the QN. The $\Delta-\Sigma$ architecture is said to have a Noise Shaping property that pushes the QN towards higher frequency, which then got filtered out by an equivalent low-pass filter to get a clean sampled signal.
Here are my confusions:

If the QN is w.r.t. the signal being sampled, obviously the QN is input-dependent, how can one conclude it's white noise?
My understanding is that the $\Delta-\Sigma$ modulator is actually using the relative "position" of the input signal inside $\pm V_{ref}$ interval to create an equivalent asymmetric triangle wave, and compare that to 0, to generate a PWM-like signal where the percentage of the logical "1"s is used to calculate the actual value. I thought maybe the uniform QN could be referring to the triangle wave? -Still, the spectrum of triangle wave isn't uniform either.

That's it, the problem that remained in my head for more than 10 years. I didn't choose to become a hardware engineer anyway but I'm still a hobbist and always want to learn more.
Thanks.

Q-noise for Sigma Delta is not uniform in freq. If the noise is shaped, then it ISN'T white noise, is it?  For traditional ADC's with a sine wave that isn't a submultiple of the sampling rate, the error for one sample will be completely independent from the error from the next sample assuming our signal is changing fast enough to transition more than one boundary. This is the recipe for white noise: independent from sample to sample. The Sigma Delta won't be independent and also is NOT white, and we benefit from this noise shaping!

@DanBoschen Thanks for the explaination Dan! So the very basic of white noise is samples being independent from each other. In order to achieve this, the signal freq shouldn't be a submultiple of the sample freq, and the signal must itself be noisy(of course everything is noisy) and at least larger than 1 LSB(of the equivalent resulotion, I suppose, not the internal 1-bit comparator or so). Then the sigma-delta architecture shapes and filters this noise to provide clean readout, is that right?

Not exactly-- The signal need not be noisy at all just not an integer relationship with the sampling clock and large enough and fast enough to transition a few levels from sample to sample for the result to be "pseudo-random" with the error from one sample to be independent from the others. And the sigma delta alone just provides a 1 bit data stream, we need to filter that to get the "clean" output. The noise from the sigma delta is not white but shaped. I think you get the shaping part, to be white the spectrum must be flat.

This post may be helpful to you: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40259/what-are-advantages-of-having-higher-sampling-rate-of-a-signal/40261#40261

@DanBoschen Now I totally understand you. But what if the input signal is slow, even as slow as a noiseless clean DC (just imagine)? Does that mean the Delta-Sigma ADC will work incorrectly? From my understandings about the mechanism it will still work - Say a 1V DC signal and 1.6V ref, when the internal DA outputs -1.6V the subtractor outputs 2.6V, and when DA switches to 1.6V the subtractor gives -0.6V, the output of the subtractor forms the slope of integration so the 1-bit AD outputs have different 1s and 0s, and proportion of 1 or 0 gives the final readout.

My explanation was for the white noise result of a standard ADC- the sigma delta noise is not white so there is a different explanation (if there is interest I can add another answer here detailing that once I have more time -in a week or so). Sigma delta works fine with DC or AC signals.

@DanBoschen Thank you and it would be appreciated if you can add the answer. I am interested in the sigma delta noise.

I've never considered the quantization error of 1-bit $\Sigma \Delta$ modulators to be uniform.


If the QN is w.r.t. the signal being sampled, obviously the QN is input-dependent, how can one conclude it's white noise?

It usually mathematically isn't, but for most input signals and most things where we care about the spectral shape of noise, that approximation is good enough.
Of course you're right, if you, say, fed in a clean sine wave with close-to-full-range amplitude into an ADC, and sine wave frequency and sample rate are rationally related, the resulting noise must be periodic.
Luckily, that never happens, because typically, you design your signal chain such that the noise you're expecting in the signal is in the order of the least significant bit(s) of the ADC. That way, you "resolve" that forced dependency of quantization noise and signal. Furthermore, in many applications, the signal that you sample is almost certainly not at a "small coprime fraction" rational relationship to the sampling rate.

My understanding is that the Δ−Σ modulator is actually using the relative "position" of the input signal inside ±Vref interval to create an equivalent asymmetric triangle wave, and compare that to 0, to generate a PWM-like signal where the percentage of the logical "1"s is used to calculate the actual value. I thought maybe the uniform QN could be referring to the triangle wave? -Still, the spectrum of triangle wave isn't uniform either.

Not quite sure if I follow you there, but the shape of the (internal, potentially also purely theoretical) comparator input wave doesn't appear at the output.

Say I have a 4-bit ADC with Vref=1.6V, that'll give me 0.1V/LSB, now if I put in a DC signal at 0.31V, theoratically the quantization noise is a constant 0.01V. But since noise is everywhere so I design my frontend so that the 0.31V is "polluted" by a noise of exactly 0.05Vpp to create a signal that actually ranges from 0.26~0.36V, which then got processed and filtered in the ADC to provide a "statistical" 0.31V output. - Is this understanding correct?

I have very strong problems with your usage of words: Noise is not "constant", and noise is not "exactly 0.05Vpp". Noise is inherently a random process, and you'll need statistical terms to describe it! I think you got the core idea right, but you really should be careful with the terminology there – thinking of noise as having exact peak-to-peak voltages can easily lead to misunderstandings :)

Yes I totally agree with you, noise cannot be treated as an exact variable so a statistical description must be used. But I'd like to argue that for the term "constant", In that context I was talking about a theoratical and imaginary condition where the input signal is a pure and clean DC without noise. Since by definition the QN is input signal "mods" the LSB, so QN is a noise only if input signal is noisy, in which case the above QN is actually not a noise. And as for the "exactly 0.05Vpp", would it be better if I change that into "a noise of $3\sigma = 0.05Vpp$"?
